# how to call and echo a value from my database for a a certain user using username to identify the user

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table named users on my database which is suppose to hold balance in BTC and Cash in two of its rows
I have a php file which i have used to echo the value for each user using the user's username to identify the particular user, but for some reason the echoed data contains the whole row for BTC and Cash value instead of identifying the user using the username and displaying only the value in the column for BTC and Cash where it suppose to display the balance on my website.
So what i am basically looking for is the code to call the data from my database and using username to identify user, display the value for the user.

This is the html where it suppose to display the user's balance on my website

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<div class="logged-user-w text-center avatar-inline">
        <div class="logged-user-info-w">
    <div class="logged-user-name">
        <a class="text-primary" href="profile.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a>

    </div>
//BTC balance//
    <div class="logged-user-role">
            <a class="text-grey" href="wallet.php"><?php include('new.php')?></a>
    </div>
//Cash balance//
    <div class="logged-user-role">
            <a class="text-grey" href="cashwallet.php"><?php include('new.php')?></a>
     </div>

</div>
</html>
```

hare is the php (new.php) which is suppose to get the values from my database and echo it

```
<?php

      // Server credentials 
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Creating mysql connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checking mysql connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Writing a mysql query to retrieve data 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users bitcoin, cash";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Show each data returned by mysql
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

    <!-- USING HTML HERE : Here I am using php within html tags -->
    <p> <?php echo $row["bitcoin"]; ?></p>
    <p> <?php echo $row["cash"]; ?></p>
<?php
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Closing mysql connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You will need to add a where clause  (like: Where username  = '$user') in your SQL statement and then join users on bitcoin and bitcoin on case depending using LEFT JOIN or JOIN sytax. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT bitcoin, cash FROM users";

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is wrong change it to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

Or if you just want the fields like bitcoin and cash you may write a query as

```
$sql = "SELECT bitcoin,cash FROM users";
```

And then echo the respective variables.

Comment: i think the OP just wants `bitcoin` and `cash` so `SELECT bitcoin, cash FROM users ` would be more precise

Comment: that does not solve my problem, my main issue is how to get the value for a certain user identifying the user using the session username , the data i get when i run my code displays the data for all the users that are on the the table which i don't want i just need a value form a single column on the btc/cash rows respectively  showing for the logged in user

Comment: So for that you need to store the sessions id's for all the users in the database and then by retrieving tha data you can check for all the users. if it is eqaul to stored data or not.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Kunal Raut, change your sql statement, but if you want to select the data based on the username, then use the following.

```
$sql = "SELECT bitcoin, cash FROM users WHERE username=$_SESSION[‘USERNAME’]”
```

Or use the user id.

```
$sql = "SELECT bitcoin, cast FROM users WHERE userid= $_SESSION[‘USERID’]
```

In both examples, you would need to change the field name to match what you used in the database to hold either the username or the user id.

Comment: assuming the username i want to call is the same as the session username, how do i state that at the beginning, and call it where you have instructed me to change the field to match my db

Comment: You would have to be saving the session value in the database or call the username from the database and save that to session value.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect how to use session variables inside you sql statement.

Comment: i have tried using your answers but they keep returning the error message i set "no results" so i am guessing something is not wright, in my table i have id, username , pass, bitcoin and cash is there no way i can use any of these as a unique indicator to select the user which i want to display its cash or bitcoin balance/value.....or better still can i generate a unique indicator to select the user in question, if i can, please can someone help me with such code ....i have been on this for days, i need help